# Android scrollview: scroll down automatically over a period of time

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, game-physics, autoscroll

I am currently working on an app, this one: http://90kids.com/level-dash/ and i can't figure out how to make my screen scroll automatically like ther. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create timer task scroll your view after each particular time.
Refer Below example

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {       
            ScrollView sv =(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrl);
            sv.scrollTo(0, 10);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 100000);
```